# Mozilla add-on and var {Cc, Ci, Cu} = require("chrome");

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

i new in Mozilla addons.
I make addon who use option to off images and scripts. Used code:

```
let button_img = ToggleButton({  id: "btn2",  label: "Show/hide images",  icon: "./img1.png",  onChange: imgChange});

var {Cc, Ci, Cu} = require("chrome");
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/XPCOMUtils.jsm", this);
var PrefBranch = Cc["@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIPrefBranch);
button_img_is_cecked=0;
function imgChange(state) {
    if (state.checked) {//Blocking images
        button_img.icon="./img2.png";
        PrefBranch.setIntPref("permissions.default.image",2);//Disable images
        PrefBranch.setIntPref("permissions.default.script",2);//Disable script
        button_img_is_cecked=1
    }else {
        button_img.icon="./img1.png";
        PrefBranch.setIntPref("permissions.default.image",1);//enable images
        PrefBranch.setIntPref("permissions.default.script",1);//enable script
        button_img_is_cecked=0
    }
}
```

Code and addon works correctly, but when I send addon to checking I receive message:

Usage of flagged or non-SDK interface

Warning: This SDK-based add-on uses interfaces that aren't part of the SDK or are flagged as sensitive.

```
var {Cc, Ci, Cu} = require("chrome");
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/XPCOMUtils.jsm", this);
```

I have other variants to off images and scripts without using this imported resource?

Also this code off images for all tabs in Mozilla. Can I do it jost for one tab where my addon works?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get and set preferences using this low-level sdk module:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/preferences_service

So your code would probably look like:

```
var gPrefs = require("sdk/preferences/service");

...
gPrefs.set("permissions.default.image",1);
gPrefs.set("permissions.default.script",1);
```